# Git Shows File Changed When It Did Not

Tags: git, diff

I have a problem in a windows machine that cloned a git repo from a Linux machine.

Now git status shows that all files were changed, and if I do `git diff file` all of the lines of the code are in -, and then are added with +.

It seems like a line ending problem but I added .gitattributes to the root of my git repository stating that *.java is text, so what am I missing ?

Here is my .gitattributes file:

```
*.css text
*.html text
*.java text
*.php text
*.phtml text
*.js text
*.hbs text
*.swf binary
*.jpg binary
*.png binary
```

## update

the problem probably relates to line ending but i can't seem to resolve the issue.

`git status` shows that the file was modified. and if i do `git checkout` to the file it still shows that it was modified.

i tried editing the following core config values:

```
git config core.eol lf
git config core.autocrlf input or auto or true
```

it doesn't make any changes.. files still marked as modified.

Comment: I guess it's the line ending issue. Check `git config --get-regexp 'core\..*crlf'` settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation about auto-converting of line ending http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Setting a path as `text` enables end-of-line normalization.

On windows you should probably set the config `core.autocrlf` to `true`.